# how to make sharpoint list fields visible for certain users

Tags: sharepoint-list, conditional

I have set up a sharepoint list I maintain myself with my manager.
There is a subset of fields that are needed to see and updated by the team.
For that I created a new view that only displays the columns needed for the team.
This is only to avoid confusion and help team members to find the data essential to them, so no confidentiality issues here. But when they edit an item to edit their part, they see ALL available and editable fields.
So I used conditional formula to hide the columns I don't want to be edited by accident, what worked out pretty much with one exception: when I go back to the view that is supposed for me to see, I can't edit my part because the columns in the edit window are hidden in my view too.
I am wondering if it would be possible to check the user name that opened the item, in conditional formula.
I hope all what I just wrote makes sense

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to apply little customization on your list form.

Modern Experience: It's done using PowerApps.
Classic Page: you have to apply Javascript.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I’ll better get busy learning power apps then :-(